# How to make a link clickable in Action Mailer Views using markdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to remove content from email notifications received from a social networking website, diaspora*. 
Email notifications are received only when there is any activity on my post on diaspora*.
The email notification should contain only a link to the post on diaspora* and not the content.

The file app/views/notifier/comment_on_post.markerb contains the following code:

```
<%= comment_message(@notification.comment) %>
```

The file app/helpers/notifier_helper.rb contains this code:

```
def comment_message(comment)
   I18n.t('notifier.comment_on_post.post_activity', link: post_comment_url(comment.post, comment))
end
```

The en.yml file contains:

```
comment_on_post:
     post_activity: "Hey! There was some activity on your post. See it at %{link}."
```

I have to make the %{link} clickable in the views using markdown. Something like this:
https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/blob/develop/app/views/notifier/also_commented.markerb

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question, but I think all you need is the [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) helper

```
<%= comment_message(@notification.comment) %>
```

should be

```
<%= link_to comment_message(@notification.comment) %>
```